# Unable to DEBUG a nuget package inside a nuget package

Tags: c#, debugging, nuget, nuget-package, pdb-files

I have Nuget Package A, which I am publishing with both pdb and source.

The project inside Package A uses a Package B which was was also published with pdb and source.

Now, When I use the Package A in a separate solution, I am able to debug through Package A by putting breakpoints in src/projects of Package A. But I am unable to traverse through Package B's source as part of the debug process.

How can I achieve this?